# What does "smart with someone" mean?

Tags: meaning

> Dudley and I were in the alleyway between Magnolia Crescent and Wisteria Walk,” said Harry, speaking fast, fighting to control his temper. “Dudley thought he’d be **smart with me**, I pulled out my wand but didn’t use it. Then two dementors turned up —”

Does it mean to outsmart someone? or just another way of saying make a joke on someone?

Comment: It means being rude by saying things or making jokes in a way that shows a lack of respect. e.g. Don't get smart with me, kid. http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/smart_1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being 'smart with someone' means to be very clever with someone deliberately (For example) they don't like the other person or they want to go ahead of them in some way.

> e.g. sentence:
>
> rude person: you need to scoot over
>
> me: don't get smart with me
>
> rude person: what's your problem
>
> me: that's not how you ask

Comment: Clever, perhaps, but often with a dose of sarcasm or sass.